# Find all Persons with fogbugz api

Tags: c#, .net, fogbugz, fogbugz-api

Is there a way to get a list of all Persons using the Fogbugz API?

I'm currently using a search for cases:

```
var api = new FBApi(email, password);
string cases = api.Search("edited:\"" + datetime + "\"", "ixBug");
```

Is there something similar for getting a list of all persons?

Such as:

```
string persons = api.Search("persons:\"ixPerson\"");
```

EDIT:
I figured it out.

I'm actually using a Fogbugz API C# [wrapper](http://asp.net2.aspfaq.com/fogbugz-csharp-api-wrapper.html) that I found on he Fogcreek API site. The Wrapper doesn't expose the ListPeople function so I had to use the Cmd function to call the ListPersons Fogbugz API funciton.

```
var api = new FBApi(email, password);
string persons = api.Cmd(listPeople");
// Can use XCmd to get a XmlNodeList instead
```

Anyhow, now I have it working and I got everything that I need.